# Can 'news' be plural at least occasionally?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

> All bad news spread(s) fast.

Textbooks teach that you should use singular forms with 'news'. In the sentence above, though, the plural form sounds more natural to me, somehow.

So, is it 'spread' or 'spreads'?

Comment: Plural is not idiomatic.  We'd probably say *Bad news always spreads fast* if making a general statement of that nature.

Comment: *Bad news spreads fast* (present) but *the bad news spread fast* (past). I think part of the problem here also has to do with a possible confusion over verb tense rather than subject-verb agreement.

Answer (score 4):

*News* is an uncountable noun and, as a result, treated as singular. This is why a singular form is used.